# use specs2 in 'is' style with play2

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, specs2

```
class ServiceTest extends PlaySpecification with Mockito {

  override def is =
    s2"""
    This is Service Specification

    The Service  should create element in right way          $init

    """
  val metricId = 1
  val hashid = HashIdGenerator.hashId(metricId)
  def init = 1 mustEqual (1)

}
```

The HashIdGenerator need play application start , the play doc shows we need get a play application in this way: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaTest

```
  "Computer model" should {

  "be retrieved by id" in new WithApplication {
    // your test code
  }
  "be retrieved by email" in new WithApplication {
    // your test code
  }
}
```

but i don't like this 'should in ' style , so how can i get a play application and keep using 'is' style at the same time .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use WithApplication wrap the code depend on play application:

```
  val Id = 1
  val app = new WithApplication {
    val hashId = HashIdGenerator.hashId(Id)
  }
  val hashId = app.hashId
```